# difference between serial event value and serial port value

Tags: java, serial-port, sensors, jssc, input-devices

i am using jssc to read values from serial ports.once i write to the serial port the following callback is getting called . within that callback i can get values from the event and from serial port itself both contains different values. i want to know the difference between serial port values and serial event values does the event contain the values from serial ports?.

```
public class PortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

SerialPort serialPort;
public PortReader(SerialPort serialPort) {
    this.serialPort = serialPort;
}

@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    System.out.println("started");
    if (event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {
        try {
            String receivedData =  serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());
            System.out.println("Received response: " + receivedData);
            receivedData = serialPort.readString();
            System.out.println("Received response: " + receivedData);
        } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in receiving string from COM-port: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of JSSC event values are jssc specific while the data that event carries is from serial port.